# Is there a way to tell Upstart to log service?

Tags: upstart, nginx

In the logs directory I don't see a log file for my app (with a conf file `nomilkforme.conf`):

```
z@ubuntu:/var/log/upstart$ ls
console-setup.log.1.gz
container-detect.log.1.gz
module-init-tools.log.1.gz
networking.log.1.gz
network-interface-eth0.log.1.gz
procps.log.1.gz
procps-static-network-up.log.1.gz
procps-virtual-filesystems.log.1.gz
rsyslog.log.1.gz
ureadahead.log.1.gz
ureadahead-other.log.1.gz
```

Is there a way to tell Upstart to create a `nomilkforme.log`?

Answer (score 2):

The `console log` stanza or no console stanza at all (because log is default) should cause a log file to be generated.

If this is how your script is and it's still not generating a log file, post the `nomilkforme.conf` file.

See [this](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console) section of the cookbook for more info.